# ASP.NET MVC (razor) deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll, deployment, compilation, code-behind

I have a bunch of ASP.NET MVC pages to deploy but find that deploying the dll can be risky in terms of breaking other controller code. Is there a way to build my code using codefile like I do in web forms instead of a codebehind format so that I don't need to move a dll, it would be compiled based on the changes in the code that gets moved?

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 0):

You have been incorrectly informed.

Compilation will happen in both cases. It's usually better to publish a web site before deployment so ASP.NET doesn't spend time compiling C# into assemblies. If you have correct framework installed on the target machines, there shouldn't be any problems with precompiled code.

In fact, there are more problems with deploying the code:

- Plain source code is accessible from production, increasing risks of intellectual property theft
- First requests take longer to process due to code compilation
- You cannot be sure if there is any compile-time error present in the code